# how to change cell image in uitable view?

Tags: iphone, uitableview

i know this is to much silly question but i dont remember how to do this .

i want to make selected image when in table select image.

i want to add image in call and diffrent image in selection.

how can i do this ?

Comment: When you say select image do you mean for example, when you usually use a cell, it is white, you touch it, it highlights blue, you want to change what it highlights to (in this case another background image) ? is that right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to set the image as selected state when clicks the table view row. Use this code,

```
CGRect a=CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 100);

UIImageView *bImg=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:a];

bImg.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"YourBackGround.png"]; 

[bImg setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleToFill];

cell.selectedBackgroundView=bImg;

[bImg release];
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I could parse your question correctly, is this what you need?

```
UITableViewCell *cell;
cell.imageView.highlightedImage = theHighlightedStateImage;
```

Comment: i want to add image not highlited image ..or is this for add image ? where i write name of image ?